# add hover to two elements with shared selector if hovered of either or

Tags: css

I don't believe I can use :parent or sibling, pseudo classes with this as they are neither. They are elements completely separate from one another. I'm wondering if it's possible to do this without any JS. Pure CSS only. Below is my markup.

```
    <ul id="onsix"><!-- first instance -->
        <li id="one" class="shov one"><a class="one" href="#">Lorem Ipsum.</a></li><br>
        <li id="two" class="shov two"><a class="one" href="#">Lorem Ipsum.</a></li><br>
        <li id="three" class="shov three"><a class="one" href="#">Lorem Ipsum.</a></li><br>
    </ul>

   <div class="twosix"><!-- second instance -->
        <div id="one2" class="over shov one"></div>
        <div id="two2" class="over shov two"></div>
        <div id="three2" class="over shov three"></div>
    </div>
```

Basically I would like to add a hover effect to both instances with the `class="one"` when either instance of class one is hovered. Thus far I have tried sibling psuedo class with no success.

So, essentially these two elements.

```
        <li id="one" class="shov one"><a class="one" href="#">Lorem Ipsum.</a></li><br>
```

*and*

```
        <div id="one2" class="over shov one"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add the information over which element you exactly want to hover and what elements should get the class (in your example)?

Comment: In your `id=onsix` all of the anchors have the same class `<a class="one" ...>` — is that intentional, or a typo? Also to clarify — if you hover over `<div id="three2"...>` and get the hover effect, you _also_ want `<li id="three"...>` to have the hover effect because they both have `class="three"` (?)

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas Updated.

Comment: It is, essentially a dupe of the "parent selector" question. This is not possible with CSS as CSS cannot affect element UP the DOM. Javascript would be required.

Comment: Thanks you @Paulie_D , for you candor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this without javascript you would need a selector that describes a chain like
 *.one:parent—sibling—child.one*

However, there is [still no parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) in CSS3, so no, you can't do this without javascript.

There *are* things such as [EQCSS](http://elementqueries.com/) which has a [`$parent`](https://codepen.io/tomhodgins/post/a-parent-selector-for-css) "selector", but that requires javascript itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the starts with tag.

```
li [id^="one"]:hover
```

**[ ]** begins and closes your containing condition
**id** is to specify that we are looking for an id you can also use class
**^** specifies starts with other options include **$** ends with, ***** contains string
**"one"** the condition we are passing.

Comment: Thanks, this is cool, however doesn't work. Updated my question for accuracy.